# How can I arrange divs of different height on 2 lines, cannot edit HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make two lines of divs. The divs are of different height. Like in the image bellow.

These divs are wordpress posts. They should go like this: first on the left, next one on the right, next one on the left etc.

Unfortunately, I can change only the style of the div that will contain the wordpress post. **I cannot add html tags** or make two columns in the html. So, can it be done only by styling the div element?

The divs don't have IDs,I have to get them with `#container div{}`
[image]

The only solution I found is this one:

```
div{float:left; width:345px; min-height:680px; max-height:680px;}
```

This works, but some of my divs are above 680px and they get on top of the others.

Comment: Do these div elements have unique ids? Can you add one or a class? If not maybe [CSS: even and odd rules](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) might help you...

Comment: no, they do not have id at all. I get them with #container div{} I will look at even and odd although I see that there is no support for IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want every other div pulled aside like this:

```
div:nth-child(2n+3) {
 float:left;
}

div:nth-child(2n+4) {
 float:right;
}
```

The +3 and +4 are assuming there are 3 divs before these you don't want to touch.  This would need tweaking for your specific situation, but without seeing specific structure it's impossible to say anything for certain.

Comment: There is only `#container` and in it this div loop for wordpress posts.

Comment: Then try `#container div:nth-child(2n) { float: left; }` etc.  This would alter every other div inside `#container`.

Comment: You can also use `:first-child` to refer to the first only (commonly used for table headers etc).  Also, you may not need the `n`.  Been a while since I had need to use this.

Comment: Or even better, with css3 you can use `div:nth-child(odd)`.  Read here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: with `:nth-child(2n)` it works fine. I think there is better support than `(odd)` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div id="left-side">
    <div class="pull-left">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right-side">
    <div class="pull-left">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left">
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
left-side {
    float: left;
}

right-side {
    float: right;
}

pull-left{ 
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But my question wasn't complete, I can add only style to the div element. I cannot modify the html.